# Infragistics grid in win desk top application, design view is not available for viewing

Tags: visual-studio-2010, grid, infragistics

I have a weird situation with Infragistics grid in desktop windows application. It is Visual Studio 2010.

I have several grids placed in one form control. It worked fine and I was able to see both Code Behind view and Designer view to make modifications. Then several other developers worked with the same control. It still runs fine, no problem. I still can see and modify code behind. But I can not access and view design view for some reason. It just gives me the error message :

**Key already exists Parameter name: Key**

Here is call stack:

at Infragistics.Shared.KeyedSubObjectsCollectionBase.ValidateKeyDoesNotExist(String key, IKeyedSubObject ignoreObject)
at Infragistics.Shared.KeyedSubObjectsCollectionBase.ValidateKey(String key, IKeyedSubObject ignoreObject)
at Infragistics.Shared.KeyedSubObjectsCollectionBase.InternalAdd(IKeyedSubObject obj)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnsCollection.InternalAdd(UltraGridColumn column)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand.InitColumns(UltraGridBand[] oldBands)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBand.InitListManager(BindingManagerBase bindingManager, String dataMember, UltraGridBand[] oldBands)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout.ListManagerUpdated(BindingManagerBase bindingManager)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridLayout.ListManagerUpdated()
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase.Set_ListManager(Object newDataSource, String newDataMember)
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase.VerifyDataSourceAttached()
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase.DesignTimeDataSourceInitialization()
at Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.UltraGridBase.OnDesignerHostLoadComplete(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerLoaderHost.EndLoad(String rootClassName, Boolean successful, ICollection errorCollection)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.OnEndLoad(Boolean successful, ICollection errors)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.OnEndLoad(Boolean successful, ICollection errors)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerLoaderService.DependentLoadComplete(Boolean successful, ICollection errorCollection)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.BasicDesignerLoader.BeginLoad(IDesignerLoaderHost host)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.BeginLoad(DesignerLoader loader)

I really need to see and modify design view of the control.

I would highly appreciate if anybody can advise how to solve this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I was able to pinpoint the issue. It was one of the data source objects that was added drag and drop way. I opened the file ..Designer.cs and manually commented all lines with it. The design view started working again.

Thanks to everyone who was considering to assist.